# org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path, unexpected token [trying to use left join]

Tags: java, hibernate, join, left-join, hql

I've created 2 entity classes:

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "fr")
public class FR {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "pid")
    private String pId;
    @Column(name = "pname")
    private String pName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getpId() {
         return pId;
    }

    public void setpId(String pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }
}
```

**and**

```
package entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ar")
public class AR {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "value1")
    private String value1;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to **join** these tables to fetch the record.

`Query qry = session.createQuery("from FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id where FR.id=123 or FR.pId=123");`

**but getting an exception:**

`org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [FR.id], unexpected token [FR] [from entities.FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id where FR.id=123 or FR.pId=123]`

and when I'm removing **FR** from the query

`Query qry = session.createQuery("from FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id where id=123 or pId=123");`

**getting another exception:**

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from entities.FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id where id=123 or pId=123]`

I'm in a learning stage of Hibernate and don't know what to do now.

If you've any other info regarding **Left Join or the other Joins** then please share that too.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/examples?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Root#123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="entities.FR"/>
    <mapping class="entities.AR"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Main Class**

```
package hibernate.joins;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateJoins {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query qry = session.createQuery("from FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id and ( FR.id=123 or FR.pId=123 )");
        List list = qry.list();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory () {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("configurations/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **ON** clause in your query, therefore, you can not to use **where** clause separately. Just keep on adding the condition using **AND** or **OR** clause(whichever is applicable)

Comment: **did this:** `Query qry = session.createQuery("from FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id and ( FR.id=123 or FR.pId=123 )");`  **and getting a new exception:** `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from entities.FR left join AR on FR.pId = AR.id and ( FR.id=123 or FR.pId=123 )]`